# Facebook share webdialog fails to show on iOS8 simulator

Tags: ios, facebook

```
FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:params:handler
```

doesn't show anything on iOS8 simulator. I have XCode 6 and 5.1 both installed side by side and same code works on iOS7 simulator. Once or twice I got SSL Handshake failed on iOS8. It can't be my network because then it should affect iOS7 simulator too..

Answer (score 0):

I was just showing the dialog in viewDidLoad method which caused it to show but somehow before the view controller. So if I dismiss the controller the dialog will be visible. Showing the dialog in IBAction of a button works fine.